# Applying style with Visibility.Visible to a hidden control doesn't work.

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I have a label control and style defined in XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="EditModeEditedHiddenTemplate" TargetType="Control">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange" />
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</Style>
```

... other stuff ...

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Name="SomeName" Visibility="Hidden">Some content</Label>
```

Then, in code behind based on user input, i apply the style to the control like this:

```
var editModelControlStyle = new Style(control.GetType());

foreach (var setter in editModeStyleTemplate.Setters)
{
    editModelControlStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
}

editModelControlStyle.BasedOn = control.Style;

control.Style = editModelControlStyle;
```

With most dependency properties this work fine, such as Background. However, this does not work when it comes to visibility, the control is still invisible.

Can you please help me understand why this is and how to solve it?

Comment: manual value has priority over `Style.Setter`. Remove `Visibility="Hidden"` and read [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing)

Comment: Ok, precedence. I don't have control over how the controls look, so i need to figure out a way to apply the new properties without depending on styles.

Comment: Hi Cousken, I dont understand this "I don't have control over how the controls look" can you explain me in more detail?

Comment: At my job, i am not allowed to edit how this controller is defined it the XAML. It's simply not possible for me, it's outside of my controll :)

Comment: Fine, Do you have access to change the code behind of the file where the label is defined, or do you have the reference of the label??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have set the `Visibility` property inline like this:

```
<Label Name="SomeName" Visibility="Hidden" Content="Something" />
```

... then this will mean that this specified value will override any value that is set in an applied `Style`.

```
<Style x:Key="EditModeEditedHiddenTemplate" TargetType="Control">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange" />
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" /><!-- No effect-->
</Style>
```

`DependencyProperty`s can be set from many different sources, such as `Style`s, `Animation`s and inline to name but a few, and as such, they have a particular order of precedence, which specifies which source should override other sources. You can find out more about this in the Dependency Property Setting Precedence List section of the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing) page on MSDN.

From that list, you can see that only `Animation`s and Property system coercion can override an inline property value. Therefore if you can't remove the `Visibility="Hidden"` from the XAML, you can only set the `Visibility` property to `Visible` in an animation, or through property coercion. However, these would both require a change to the XAML in order to work. This is how you could change the `Visibility` value in an `Animation`:

```
<Label Name="SomeName" Visibility="Hidden" Content="Something">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:1">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

I set the `Storyboard.BeginTime` to 1 second so that you could see the text appear, but equally, this could be set to 0 seconds to happen as soon as it is loaded. Property coercion would require that you data bind a property to the `Visibility` property:

```
<Label Name="SomeName" Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty}" Content="Something" />
```

However, if you cannot change the XAML on the `Label`, then you have no way to make the `Visibility` value `Visible` in XAML alone. It *would* be possible to do this in code though... you just need some condition in which to trigger the change. In this example, I have just added a click handler to the `Grid` to gain access to the code behind:

```
<Grid PreviewMouseDown="OnPreviewMouseDown" Background="Transparent">
    <Label Name="SomeName" Visibility="Hidden" Content="Something" />
</Grid>
```

...

```
private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SomeName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

However, you would *still* need to change the XAML to do even this. Perhaps you could attach a handler in code instead?

Comment: Wow that's a very very good answer! thanks a lot. How do you mean attach a handler? At this point i can do anything besides editing the original XAML. DO you mean like this? <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Visibility}" Value="Visibility.Hidden">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

Comment: No, I meant attach an event handler in code because you can't do it in XAML: `SomeName.PreviewMouseDown += OnPreviewMouseDown;`.